# JQuery Function Calling On Click Of Anchor Tag Inside Kendo Grid MVC

Tags: kendo-ui, anchor

I created a column inside my kendo grid in mvc as follows with a anchor tags based on true or false of a field.

```
columns.Bound(c => c.IsMapped).Width(140).ClientTemplate(
"# if (IsMapped == true) { #" +                                                                    
"<a href='DeleteMap?Id=#=Id#' class='btn btn-xs default'>UnMap </a>" +
"# } else { #" +                                                                  
"<a onclick=\"Show(this);\" href='javascript:void(0);'   
class='btn btn-xs default'> Map </a>" +
"# } #" );
```

The first anchor tag is working fine and invoking my controller action. But the second anchor tag is not invoking the java script function. My Java script function is as follows.

```
function Show(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Test1');
        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));            
        var wnd = $("#portal").data("kendoWindow");
        wnd.refresh({
            url: "Test",
            data: { id: dataItem.Id, pvid: dataItem.PVId }
        });
        wnd.center().open();
    };
```

when I look in the page source, the second anchor tag is rendered as follows that has no onclick attribute set.

```
<a class="k-grid-filter" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="k-icon k-    
filter"></span></a>
```

Anything wrong in my code? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Personally this is what I would do for your template to make it easier to maintain and test.

Restructure your current template from the nested JavaScript in your razor code and pull it out into a separate function like so:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.IsMapped).Width(140).ClientTemplate("#=unMap(data)#");
```

then create the associated function:

```
function unMap(data){
    var retString = ''; 
    if(data.IsMapped === true) {
        retString = '<a href="DeleteMap?Id=' + data.Id + '" class="btn btn-xs default">UnMap </a>'; 
    }
    else {
        retString = '<a data-map="'+ data.Id + '" href="#" class="btn btn-xs default"> Map </a>';
    }

    return retString; 
}
```

then in the events config for the grid add this:

```
.Events(events => events.DataBound("onBoundData"))
```

then attach this JavaScript function:

```
 function onBoundData(e) {
      $("a[data-map]").on("click", function (me) {
                me.preventDefault();
          //do your Show(this) method in here 
      });

 }
```

this will then bind the event to the links with the `data-map` attribute.

Hope this helps and if you have any follow up questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building anchor tag like this

```
onclick=\"Show(this);\"
```

change it to

```
onclick='Show(this);'
```

Comment: i tried it too. it also doesn't work for me. Thanks for your time

Comment: you can see few sample over here , it will help. [link](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq)

Answer (score 0):

the following code worked for me. Here I am assigning a css class to anchor element and handling click event of anchor element using jquery based on css class.

```
@Html.ActionLink("UnMap", "DeleteMap", new { Id = @item.Id })
    </text>).ClientTemplate(
          "# if (IsMapped == true) " + @"{# <a href=""DeleteMap?                                                                               
          Id=#=Id#"">UnMap</a>" + "# } " + 
          @"else {# <a href=""\#"" class='myCommand'>Map</a>" + "# } #").Width(75);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats working for me

**cshtml**
columns.Bound(c => c.REQUESTNUMBER).Title("Request ID").ClientTemplate("#=urlMap(data)#").Width(140);

**js**

var urlMap = function(obj){
        return "" + obj.REQUESTNUMBER + "";
    }